# Extjs 6 : How to set convert function of the fields dynamically in extjs while creating dynamic cols of a grid

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I am creating dynamic cols poc in there i am using json data to bind the columns and as well as fields..when i created the convert function in the fields of the json data then the convert function is not working.

Below is the sample POC

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12sa

There in the column text 4 i am showing 7,2,3 values and in the convert function i am trying to add the values with 10 and so it should show 17,12,13.

Please let me know how can i set the convert function in the json data

Comment: Try defining a model class to be used by the store, and put the convert functions in that. Why are you trying to do it all in the metachange event handler?

Comment: The problem is not what you think. Convert functions run normally with your code in the example. Your function does wrong. I couldnt understand what u try to do so i cant help with it. Try to use `parseInt` for the variables you used to add.